# Test reviews (audits) when edit is selected

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

It seems somewhat arbitrary that by selected edit it synonymous with selecting `Accept` or `No Action Needed` from the perspective of the test.  While in reality, selecting edit has not completed any action.

Can this feature be reviewed?  Usually when I see anything that I think needing editing I select it right away so I can make edits as I read through the post, should I later decide the edit needs to be rejected or the post flagged, I will cancel and do so. I don't think it's appropriate to be told to "keep your eyes peeled" simply because edit was selected.

Comment: Becuase the audits are so horrible, you shouldn't be trying to improve them. My fat fingers have caused this before to me, but I just keep going.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Well if they are so horrible, maybe the edit click action should be considered as failing the test.